CMake variable naming the C++ standard library implementation or path
CMake as used to compile C++ code has a variable CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID that generally identifies the compiler in use as GCC, Clang, MSVC, Nvidia, etc. Is there a similar variable that identifies that C++ standard library implementation that will be referenced in the build? E.g. like "libstdc++" (from GCC), "libc++" (from LLVM), "MSVC++" (Microsoft), "stlport" (various ancient C++ implementations shipped with this).
I don't see anything listed at https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html but I don't know if that's actually comprehensive.
While this hypothetically could be used for various better- or ill-advised purposes of in-code variation, I actually just want to print it at configure-time in each of several projects that users need to be link-compatible, so that it's easier to diagnose 'missing symbol' errors when a mixing of standard libraries is the cause.

No, CMake doesn't have this. You have to detect it yourself nowadays.

@zaufi Thanks. Since you say 'nowadays', was there some historical way of doing this? Or, do you know of some project that does this in their CMake whose code is available to reference?
